# Run jQuery Script if Numbers Match

Tags: jquery, match

I'm trying to find a way of triggering a jQuery script if the numbers on two lines match like this:

```
CRC1: 82051E84
CRC2: 82051E84
```

Those lines would be pasted into a textarea and a submit button would be used. If the 8 digits after the CRC1: and CRC2: prefixes match then I need the word 'Match' to appear in the div below the textarea.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mobius1/6DdvV/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var areaContent = $('#text').val();
    var lines   = areaContent.split(/^/m);

    var prefixLen = 'CRC1: '.length;
    var crc1 = lines[0].substr(prefixLen);
    var crc2 = lines[1].substr(prefixLen);

    $('#output').text( crc1 === crc2 ? 'Matched!' : 'Not matched!' );
    return false;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6DdvV/20/) with updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Your way to go is to use something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6DdvV/27/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I hacked up quickly.  It might not be the most efficient, but it gets the job done.  It also will match more than just 2 CRCs.

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var text = $("#text").val().split('\n'),
        crc = $.map(text, function(v) {
            v = /CRC\d+:\s(.*)/.exec(v);
            return v != null ? v[1] : null;
        }),
        match = $.grep(crc, function(v, i) {
            return $.inArray(v, crc) === i;
        });
    $('#output').text(match.length === 1 ? 'Match' : 'No Match');
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6DdvV/31/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

http://jsfiddle.net/6DdvV/30/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function() {

        var lines = $("#text").val().split("\n");
        var num_1=lines[0].split(": ")[1];
        var num_2=lines[1].split(": ")[1];
        if(num_1==num_2)
        {
           $("#output").html("Match");
        }
    });


    $("#clear").click(function() {;
        $("#output").text("");

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Fiddle, this should do you:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {

    var str = $("#text").val();
    var lines = str.split("\n");

    if(lines[0].substr(4) == lines[1].substr(4)){
        $("#output").html("Matched");
    } else {
        $("#output").html("Not Matched");
    };

});
```

So we're splitting the string into it's lines, and then checking the output to match.